# How to build documentations project placed outside of docs directory using ReadTheDocs?

Tags: read-the-docs

I am generating documentation project using `ReadThedocs` `(mkdocs)`. But It's generating documentation project for the `.md` files which are placed in `docs` directory. My requirement is, I want to build documentation project for every `.md` file placed anywhere in the github repository.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify in the Mkdocs configuration (`mkdocs.yml`) the location of your [documentation directory](http://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/configuration/#docs_dir) to be the current directory `'.'`.

Example:

```yaml
site_name: My Documentation Project
docs_dir: '.'
```

By default, the Mkdocs looks in a subdirectory of your project labled `docs`:

> `docs_dir`
>
> Lets you set the directory containing the documentation source markdown files. This can either be a relative directory, in which case it is resolved relative to the directory containing you configuration file, or it can be an absolute directory path.
>
> default: `'docs'`

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in MkDocs by default. See this [GitHub issue thread for rationale](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/issues/1276). There is however a plugin called [mkdocs-same-dir](https://github.com/oprypin/mkdocs-same-dir) that can be used to achieve this.